# How do I burn FullHD movie in linux so it can be played in blueray player?

Tags: linux, video, blu-ray, dvdauthor

I have prepared a wedding slideshow movie with Imagination. I have successfully created a PAL 720x578 DVD with menus and so on with DVDauthor (with help of Bombono DVD) and I have nice disk playable in standard DVD player.

Imagination supports export to 1920x1080 FullHD resolution to a VOB MPEG2 file. The movie plays nice on my laptop. The size of the movie is relatively small, it still fits on a single DVD, so I thought I could burn a blueray-like Fullhd movie, so it could be played in HD by people, who have playstation or blueray players.

How to burn a blueray compatibile movie? Is it possible to modify DVDauthor xml config files to keep menus and all the rest from my previous SD DVD and just replace movies with HD versions?

Comment: If either of these answers were helpful, feel free to upvote them or mark them as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://irishjesus.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/blu-ray-movie-authoring-in-linux/) is one guide how to create Blue ray in Linux from 2010. The bigest problem seems to be UDF 2.5 write support which could prevent you from creating Blu-ray filesystem. [More info](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/why-is-there-still-no-support-for-creating-udf-2-5-2-6-images-in-linux-945950/)
It seems that Nero for Linux can create Blue-ray filesystem successfully according to [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1605152) but I can't find the program on Nero site anymore. It seems it doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In order to burn to bluray you would require a bluray burner, a normal DVD burner will not work and you will require bluray writable discs, neither of which are cheap.